# Is there a browser extension that can record all user activity on a site, for the purposes of reporting bugs

Tags: tools, chrome, action-recording, debugging

We have a bug report coming in which is extremely user-specific, only one user is reporting it and furthermore they are *only* getting the error on their office wifi.

it would help me to able to see the user's console output, but I feel like a non-technical user might not understand how to do that. Is there some browser extension I can instruct the user to install, so that it will automatically record a video of their interaction and somehow include the console output? Then they could download and send it to me, so I can help debug.

Answer (score 1):

[Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) can log all HTTP requests and responses that your computer does, providing also good filtering and archiving features.

From the frontend side, any video recorder it's sufficient.

[Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana) is a data visualization tool many people use for investigating server-side logs.

If you match timestamps of these three, you may understand how the user acts from the browser click to the DB actions.

And if you match timestamps of these two, you will under

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are tools you can deploy to your web-application to monitor the application behavior including JavaScript errors, I will give two as an example.

A "cheap"/free one to get started:

> Basic error detection and alerts for hobbyists and small companies
>   looking to kickstart error monitoring
>
> https://www.bugsnag.com/pricing

A full blown monitoring expensive one: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/browser-pro-features/javascript-errors-page-detect-analyze-errors

Comment: hmm, I hadn't considered that. We are already using Rollbar for backend, not sure about front end. I would need the ability to lookup errors by user though. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this without additional "infrastructure", for example a browser extension that the user can use to quickly log network and console errors for a specific period of interaction